# How can I hide the page header (title) for just a specific page

Tags: 2013, css, page-layout, html, settings

I'd like to hide the header on my homepage (the `<h1 id="pageContentTitle" .. >` element.) I could use some CSS like

```
#pageContentTitle{ display:none; }
```

But because my CSS is referenced in the master file, this effects all pages on my site, where I would like to only change one.

I've also considered using some jQuery:

```
$('#pageContentTitle').filter(function(){
    return $(this).find('a:contains(Home)').length;
}).remove();
```

Which works, but has issues. Firstly the header is displayed momentarily until the JavaScript is executed, secondly this still needs to run on every page which seems like overkill.

I would have thought this would be quite a common desire so was hoping to find an option in the Page Settings but couldn't find anything yet.

Is there a better way of doing this?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Add the following CSS and reference it from your masterpage:

```
<style>

#aspnetForm[action*="Home.aspx"] #pageContentTitle {display:none;}

</style>
```

Comment: Brilliant, the form scope is what I needed. Thanks.

Answer (score 3):

You can easily add a content editor webpart and add in your CSS in the HTML editor.

Or you can add your CSS to a text file, then using a content editor webpart, you can reference that text file and it will include the css in that page.

Comment: I've tried your suggestion, and it works, but since the content editor webpart is presumably loaded after the page load, my title still shows up momentarily before being hidden.

Comment: It is inevitably going to show for a split second before the css hides it.

Comment: Sure, because the CSS is dynamically loaded. I thought there may well be an option provided by sharepoint so as to not include the header altogether. I guess not.

Comment: When I try this SPO removes the css code from my content editor.

Answer (score 0):

you can edit the page directly using sharepoint designer, then add your snippet of code directly, it will break the page definition... but that normally isn't a big deal.

Comment: I did try that yes, but like you said I got complaints about the page definition. Should I not worry about this warning?

Comment: Nope you should be good!

Comment: How do you get rid of the banner `The Current page has been customized from its template. Revert to Template` that shows on the customized page?

Answer (score -1):

You could edit the page in SharePoint Designer, and add the CSS to the page.

Comment: You need to add more detail about how to do it.